# Creating different functions in a loop - Flask/Python

Tags: python, flask

I'm currently working with the flask framework and I need to be able to create from a dictionary a web page for each element of this dictionary.

So I started with the idea of creating these pages through a for loop that will run through the dictionary:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

test={}
test["Louvre_Museum"]= "Rue de Rivoli, 75001 Paris"
test["Eiffel_Tower"]="Champ de Mars, 5 Avenue Anatole France, 75007 Paris"
test["Triumphal_Arch"]="Place Charles de Gaulle, 75008 Paris"
monum = []
for cle in test.keys():
    monum.append(cle)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "HOMEPAGE TEST !"

for i in range(len(monum)):
    @app.route('/monum'+str(i)+'')
    def monum_i():
        name_monum = monum[i]
        adress_monum = test[nom_monum]
        return "Nom: {} --- Adresse: {}".format(name_monum, adress_monum)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The program works correctly until it reaches the definition of the functions.

I wanted to create different functions in the loop called: "monum_0, monum_1, monum_2 etc...) which doesn't work.

For python "monum_i" is just a string and there is only one function that is created which has this name.

And this is a problem for the second pass in the loop where the program defines a function that already exists and so I have an error.

I would therefore like to know whether it is possible to define functions in an automated way in the same way as my example.

Answer (score 2):

No, this doesn't work and it's not at all the recommended way to do things in a backend.

A better way to do this is to use a single `monum` function and use a parameter to define the content of the webpage you want to display.

For example:

```
from flask import request

...

@app.route('/monum')
def monum():
    name_monum = request.args.get('name_monum')
    adress_monum = test[nom_monum]
    return "Nom: {} --- Adresse: {}".format(name_monum, adress_monum)
```

(And remember to handle errors)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but you might consider using a variable in the url instead.

```py
@app.route('/monum/<page>')
def index(page):
  if page in monum:
      return "Nom: {} --- Adresse: {}".format(page, monum[page])
  # raise a 404 or something
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I am adding my reply as an answer;

Are you calling the function anywhere? Is "`@app.route('/monum'+str(i)+'')`" supposed to do it? If so, should it not be "`@app.route('/monum_'+str(i)+'')`"? Otherwise, it might be easier to apply a `"Nom: {} --- Adresse: {}".format(monum[i], test[monum[i]])` into a for loop so you don't create a lot of functions that you'd use only once.